# A macro to typeset a difficult table

Tags: tables, macros, pgfplotstable

The following table was created with the following LaTeX-code (mwe):

[image: table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\newtabulinestyle{stip=on 1.5pt off 2pt}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[0.8l]X[2.5l]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]} \hline
\rowfont{\bfseries} \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*} {NUMBERS}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Type} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Size} &
 \multirow{2}{*}{All} \\
 & & A & B & Big & Small & \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Good}  & 1 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 5\\ \tabucline[stip]{-}
 \multirow{3}{*}{Ugly} & Cow & 7  & 1 & 4 & 4 & 8 \\ \tabucline[stip]{2-}
 & Goat & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\ \tabucline[stip]{2-}
 & Horse & 2& 1 & 3 & 0 & 3 \\ \tabucline[stip]{-}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Bad}& 12 & 1 & 6 & 7 & 13  \\ \hline
 \rowfont{\bfseries} \multicolumn{2}{l}{TOTAL} & 23 & 9 & 15 & 17 & 32 \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to create a macro that makes such tables from the following input?

```
 \begin{mytable}[NUMBERS]
 1 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 5 \\ 
 7 & 1 & 4 & 4 & 8 \\
 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\
 2 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 3 \\
 12 & 1 & 6 & 7 & 13 \\
 23 & 9 & 15 & 17 & 32
 \end{mytable}
```

I have been playing around with pgfplotstable for a while, but especially the multirows are giving me a headache.

(Ideally, even the sums would be automatically calculated and an error would be returned if the numbers did not match. (A + B = Big + Small).  But this is luxury rather than necessary.)

Comment: Some information you should probably give:  will your table always have the same headings?  Will it always have the same dimensions?

Comment: @Scott H. The answer is yes in both cases: it is always the exact same table, except for the numbers in it and the content of the very first cell ("NUMBERS").  So in fact just "prepending" a given first column (in fact a double column including multirows and multicolumns) and a first row would be a major step in the good direction that I have not managed to take yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Updated answer shows two versions, a simple one without calculation and checks and a second one which does the calculation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\newtabulinestyle{stip=on 1.5pt off 2pt}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[0.8l]X[2.5l]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]} \hline
\rowfont{\bfseries} \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*} {NUMBERS}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Type} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Size} &
 \multirow{2}{*}{All} \\
 & & A & B & Big & Small & \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Good}  & 1 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 5\\ \tabucline[stip]{-}
 \multirow{3}{*}{Ugly} & Cow & 7  & 1 & 4 & 4 & 8 \\ \tabucline[stip]{2-}
 & Goat & 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\ \tabucline[stip]{2-}
 & Horse & 2& 1 & 3 & 0 & 3 \\ \tabucline[stip]{-}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Bad}& 12 & 1 & 6 & 7 & 13  \\ \hline
 \rowfont{\bfseries} \multicolumn{2}{l}{TOTAL} & 23 & 9 & 15 & 17 & 32 \\ \hline
\end{tabu}


\def\mytable[#1]#2\\#3\\#4\\#5\\#6\\#7\end#8{%
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[0.8l]X[2.5l]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]} \hline
\rowfont{\bfseries} \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*} {#1}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Type} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Size} &
 \multirow{2}{*}{All} \\
 & & A & B & Big & Small & \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Good}  &#2\\\tabucline[stip]{-}
 \multirow{3}{*}{Ugly} & Cow & #3 \\ \tabucline[stip]{2-}
 & Goat & #4\\ \tabucline[stip]{2-}
 & Horse & #5 \\ \tabucline[stip]{-}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Bad}& #6 \\ \hline
 \rowfont{\bfseries} \multicolumn{2}{l}{TOTAL} & #7 \\ \hline
\end{tabu}%
\end{mytable}}

 \begin{mytable}[NUMBERS]
 1 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 5 \\ 
 7 & 1 & 4 & 4 & 8 \\
 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\
 2 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 3 \\
 12 & 1 & 6 & 7 & 13 \\
 23 & 9 & 15 & 17 & 32
 \end{mytable}


\def\testrowone#1&#2&#3&#4&#5\\{%
\ifnum\numexpr#1+#2\relax=#5\else \typeout{A+B != All}\fi
\ifnum\numexpr#3+#4\relax=#5\else \typeout{big+small != All}\fi
}

\def\cella#1&#2&#3&#4&#5\\{#1}
\def\cellb#1&#2&#3&#4&#5\\{#2}
\def\cellc#1&#2&#3&#4&#5\\{#3}
\def\celld#1&#2&#3&#4&#5\\{#4}
\def\celle#1&#2&#3&#4&#5\\{#5}

\def\mytableb[#1]#2\\#3\\#4\\#5\\#6\\#7\end#8{%
\testrowone#2\\
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[0.8l]X[2.5l]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]} \hline
\rowfont{\bfseries} \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*} {#1}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Type} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Size} &
 \multirow{2}{*}{All} \\
 & & A & B & Big & Small & \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Good}  &#2\\\tabucline[stip]{-}
 \multirow{3}{*}{Ugly} & Cow & #3 \\ \tabucline[stip]{2-}
 & Goat & #4\\ \tabucline[stip]{2-}
 & Horse & #5 \\ \tabucline[stip]{-}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Bad}& #6 \\ \hline
 \rowfont{\bfseries} \multicolumn{2}{l}{TOTAL} &
\the\numexpr \cella#2\\+\cella#3\\+\cella#4\\+\cella#5\\+\cella#6\\ \relax &
\the\numexpr \cellb#2\\+\cellb#3\\+\cellb#4\\+\cellb#5\\+\cellb#6\\ \relax &
\the\numexpr \cellc#2\\+\cellc#3\\+\cellc#4\\+\cellc#5\\+\cellc#6\\ \relax &
\the\numexpr \celld#2\\+\celld#3\\+\celld#4\\+\celld#5\\+\celld#6\\ \relax &
\the\numexpr \celle#2\\+\celle#3\\+\celle#4\\+\celle#5\\+\celle#6\\ \relax 
\end{tabu}%
\end{mytableb}}

 \begin{mytableb}[NUMBERS]
 1 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 5 \\ 
 7 & 1 & 4 & 4 & 8 \\
 1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\
 2 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 3 \\
 12 & 1 & 6 & 7 & 13 \\
 \end{mytableb}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. Your answer is a nice example of what 'simple/plain' TeX can do, thank you!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- oh, please don't mash the contents of each line up against the rule above it!  you know better!

Comment: If using this code please add `\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}` before the table to avoid causing pain to @barbarabeeton

Comment: Don't worry, I have taken `\tabulinesep` precautions.

Comment: Ah so @barbarabeeton will be able to sleep easily tonight:-)

Comment: Wonderful to see Jupiter arguing with Minerva here on TeX.SE...

Answer (score 5):

A half-baked [`pgfplotstable`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplotstable) solution. The column sums are missing but sanity check on the sums of rows are implemented (gives the stupid error in the screenshot if there is a discrepancy). Also the upper left corner text is optional you can change it when entering the table. With this you don't need to enter your data in a tabular format.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,multirow,booktabs}

\pgfplotstableset{toughtable/.style={
    every head row/.style={before row={\toprule
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{#1}}} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Type} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Size} &\multirow{2}{*}{All}\\
                           },
                                   after row=\midrule
                               },
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        create on use/myfirstcol/.style ={create col/set list={Good,Ugly,,,Bad,\textbf{TOTAL}}},%A dummy column
        create on use/mysecondcol/.style={create col/set list={,Cow,Goat,Horse,}},%A dummy column
        create on use/summationcol/.style={
                  create col/expr={\thisrowno{0}+\thisrowno{1}-\thisrowno{2}-\thisrowno{3}==0?\thisrowno{0}+\thisrowno{1}:0}
                            },
        columns={myfirstcol,mysecondcol,[index]0,[index]1,[index]2,[index]3,summationcol},
        columns/myfirstcol/.style={string type,column name=,
            assign cell content/.code={%
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=1\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\multirow{3}{*}{Ugly}}\fi
            }
        },
        columns/mysecondcol/.style={string type,column name=},
        columns/summationcol/.style={string type,column name=,
        assign cell content/.code={
            \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}==0?int(1):int(0)}
                \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\relax
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{Chicken Run!!}%
                \else
                \pgfmathparse{int(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@unprocessed cell content})}
                \edef\temp{\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\pgfmathresult}}\temp
                \fi
                }
      },
        display columns/2/.style={column name=A},
        display columns/3/.style={column name=B},
        display columns/4/.style={column name=Big},
        display columns/5/.style={column name=Small},
        every row no 1/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\cmidrule{2-7}},
        every row no 2/.style={after row=\cmidrule{2-7}},
        every row no 3/.style={after row=\hline},
        every row no 4/.style={after row=\hline},
        }
}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[toughtable=NUMBERS]{
 1   4  2   3 
 7   1  3   4
 1   2  0   3
 2   1  3   0
 12  1  6   7
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'll try to get the columns sum hopefully soon.