# Recursively defined macros in TeX

Tags: macros, recursion

After receiving a nice answer to a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83112/a-macro-to-typeset-a-difficult-table), I got enthousiastic and tried to create a macro `\sum` such that `\sum<1+2+3>` would be expanded into 6.

My idea was to work recursively, using the parsing functionality of `\def`. For instance, the following code outputs "7+6+5"

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\sumtestX<#1+#2>{\ifx\empty#2{#1}\else{\sumtestX<#2>+#1 }\fi}
\def\sumtest<#1>{\sumtestX<#1+\empty>}

\begin{document}
\sumtest<5+6+7>
\end{document}
```

So one would expect that turning the "+" into a real "sum" would calculate the actual sum. Nevertheless, the following code doe *not* work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\sum#1+#2{\the\numexpr#1+#2\relax}
\def\sumtestX<#1+#2>{\ifx\empty#2{#1}\else{\sum\sumtestX<#2>+#1 }\fi}
\def\sumtest<#1>{\sumtestX<#1+\empty>}

\begin{document}
\sumtest<5+6+7>
\end{document}
```

"Missing number, treated as zero" !? What's wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually some curly braces were wrong and some curly braces are missing around arguments.
For analyzing/debugging the setting `\tracingmacros=1` is helpful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\sum#1+#2{%
  \the\numexpr#1+#2\relax
}
\def\sumtestX<#1+#2>{%
  \ifx\empty#2%
    #1%
  \else
    \sum{\sumtestX<#2>}+{#1}% argument braces
  \fi
}
\def\sumtest<#1>{\sumtestX<#1+\empty>}

\begin{document}
\sumtest<5+6+7>
\end{document}
```

Of course, the recursive definitions are only an exercise?
`\sumtest` could be defined much easier:

```
\def\sumtest<#1>{\the\numexpr(#1)\relax}
```

Comment: Thank you! (Actually I was seriously going to use this >_> ... as part of my 'solution' for the problem that occurs when trying to calculate sums of "empty" strings, e.g. 5++5=10 or 4+3+=7. But I just found out that appending a +0 always solves that problem.)

Comment: @Archibald You want more exercises? Strings starting with `+` as in `+1+2`, supporting `-` as binary (and unary) operator, parentheses, ...

Answer (score 5):

LuaTeX is an ideal choice for such macros. For example, in ConTeXt, you can define:

```
\def\simplemath<#1>{\ctxlua{context(#1)}}
\starttext
\simplemath<1+2+3> \simplemath<2*4+5>
\stoptext
```

and in (Lua)LaTeX you can define:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\def\simplemath<#1>{\directlua{tex.print(#1)}}

\begin{document}
\simplemath<1+2+3> \simplemath<2*4+5>
\end{document}
```

Note that this works for all types of mathematical expressions, and not just addition.