# Using fibnum package for list numbering

Tags: enumerate

I have started using LATEX as a document processor for good. I use SCRUM for my work flow. There we usually create a list of items numbered in Fibonacci sequence. I googled for the feature in LATEX and found most topics about fibnum package are about page numbering or finding Fibonacci sequence.

My question is,

**Is there a way to generate a list numbered using Fibonacci sequence?.**

```
For example,
1 Task 1
1 Task 2
2 Task 3
3 Task 4
5
8
...
```

UPDATE:
I used enumerate for my lists. Now, I want to change my list numbering to Fibonacci sequence.

NOTE: Usually backlogs go above 50 tasks. So it's not feasible to number a list manually.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you talking about a `enumerate` environment or something special (like a package's special environment)?

Comment: I used enumerate for my lists. Now, I want to change my list numbering to Fibonacci. I didn't use any special package

Comment: You could define your own function (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83148/recursively-defined-macros-in-tex) and then use it together with `enumitem`'s label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way with `enumitem` for making enumerated lists:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fibnum}

\newcommand{\fibonacci}[1]{\expandafter\fibnum\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\fibonacci}{\fibnum}{100} % or bigger

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\fibonacci*]

\item Task
\item Task
\item Task
\item Task
\item Task
\item Task
\item Task
\item Task
\item Task
\item Task
\item Task

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If you want sections numbered as the Fibonacci sequence, after

```
\newcommand{\fibonacci}[1]{\expandafter\fibnum\csname c@#1\endcsname}
```

add also

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\fibonacci{section}}
```

[image]